# I can't install plugins on OctoPrint?

Tags: octoprint

I have installed OctoPi on my Raspberry Pi 3B+, that is connected to an MKS GEN L v1.0 motherboard for my 3D printer  (Ender 3 Pro). When I open my OctoPrint into a browser I can use it, but I wanted to install some plugins. First time I had an error that said my server was offline, after connecting my Raspberry to WiFi and setting up a static ip-address, I've connected my Raspberry to my main board, after that it said the status of OctoPrint was operational, so I expected it will work.

Sadly, it says that my installation doesn't have internet, so I still couldn't install plugins. I see that in the "connectivity check" my host is 8.8.8.8 and my port 53; I've pressed on test and there it said "server is unreachable".

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue (WIFI fine, but no internet connection to install plugins)](https://github.com/foosel/OctoPrint/issues/2474) and could well be related to firewall or blocking of certain ports by your Internet Service Provider (ISP).

I quote from the provided link (OctoPrint issue tracker):

> Disabling the connectivity check did fix the repository access. The check was configure to use google (8.8.8.8) on port various ports (22, 53, 5000, etc. Not sure the default). I do not have any firewall set up outgoing, unless it is buried in the Raspberian install that I am not aware of.

---

> I stumbled across this issue with the same problem, and I fixed the connectivity check by changing the IP to OpenDNS with 1.1.1.1 instead of the Google DNS 8.8.8.8 set by default.

---

> For me this issue was resolved when I update Date+Time on the raspberry...

Comment: For the record, 1.1.1.1 (and 1.0.0.1) is operated by CloudFlare, not OpenDNS (208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220).